# Failed to pass arguments into grid.arrange within do.call

Tags: r

I have a list which contains a variable / random number of ggplots with the following pseudo code:

```
for(i in 1 in length(ll)){
       gp_i <- ggplot(...)
       gplots[[i]] <- gp_i
}
```

Let's say there are 12 plots in this case. And I have defined a variable called "`gg_matrix`" to store the matrix for the layout of the ggplot.

```
gg_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
```

So after the for loop, I do

```
do.call(grid.arrange,list(layout_matrix = gg_matrix)).
```

This gave me an error:

```
Error in data.frame(t = t, l = l, b = b, r = r, z = z, clip = clip, name = name,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I have checked that there are 12 plots in my list. So how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please include the names of any packages that you are using in your question. Also, people appreciate questions that provide a reproducible example to replicate your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you haven't given a correct first argument to the `grid.arrange`. Following given an error.

```
grid.arrange(layout_matrix)
#Error in data.frame(t = t, l = l, b = b, r = r, z = z, clip = clip, name = 
#name,  : 
#  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Something like the following should work:

```
  do.call(grid.arrange, list(ggplots_mat, layout_matrix = gg_matrix))
```

Comment: How can I add my list into it then ? I tried `do.call(grid.arrange,list(gplots,layout_matrix=(gg_matrix)))` . And I got an error msg `Error in gList(list(list(data = list(Open = c(6, 3, 5, 7, 6, 3, 5, 6,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Comment: Glad it is working.  I think `do.call(grid.arrange, list(gg_mat, layout_matrix = lay))` should work.

Comment: no need for `do.call` now , use `grid.arrange(grobs=ggplots_mat, layout_matrix=gg_matrix)` eg(`p = replicate(4, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE) ; grid.arrange(grobs=p, layout_matrix=cbind(1:3, c(NA, NA,4)))`)